# Spring Boot - Modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build, package

I have 5 spring boot projects which can be deployed independently. I'm using gradle for dependency management. I have few java packages (src/main/java/...) in common that has been duplicated across all the services.

I would like to remove this redundancy by having the common java packages in a project and refer it from all 5 projects. How can I do that with help of spring modules. I'm new to Spring framework, and trying to do this.

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Create a separate project that contains your common classes and add it as a dependency in all  other referring projects.

Answer (score 1):

Create another project and build a jar package of the files you would like to include.

And you can reference to that package by adding next to your module gradle (Not the app gradle file):

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}
dependencies {
   compile name: 'common-1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I have a build.gradle files in my projects. Is that the one you are referring to? and once I have generated the jar where should I place it